# Add all .mp3 file in the array List from specific folder

Tags: android, kotlin, mp3

```
 private val listmp3 = ArrayList<String>()

  private fun loadmp3() {
        val YourFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/ieltsTest/"
        val file = File(YourFolderPath)
        if (file.isDirectory) {
            val files = file.listFiles()
            if (files != null && files.size > 0) {
                for (f in files) {
                    if (f.isDirectory) {
                        loadmp3(f.absolutePath)
                    } else {
                        for (i in extensions.indices) {
                            if (f.absolutePath.endsWith(extensions[i])) {
                                listmp3.add(f.absolutePath)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Log.i("audioList", listmp3.toString())
    }
```

Here, I want to list all the .mp3 in by the specific folder. I am trying to get list of the .mp3 folder. Can any body help me to get list of audio
thanks is advance............

Comment: What goes wrong with this? What does your other `loadmp3` function look like?

Comment: `if (file.isDirectory)` Replace by `if (file.exists() && file.canRead())`

Comment: `private fun loadmp3()` AND `loadmp3(f.absolutePath)` do not match. Please explain.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps issues solve (file.exists() && file.canRead()) while checking file is exists or not